# Draw a shadow behind UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, shadow

I know similar questions have been asked before, so don't get snarky and link to previous answers. The reason I am repeating this is that none of the answers have worked.

I have a UIWebView, and I want to draw a pretty drop-shadow behind it. I have tried subclassing and using some CoreGraphics goodness in drawRect:, but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place a `UIImageView` under the `UIScrollView` with a slight offset, and give the image view a shadowy-looking image.

In this case, it would be convenient to use the [`stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:) method of `UIImage` to get a shadow image that can have nicely blurred edges and corners without distorting if you alter its size.

I think [the usual quartz shadows](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-TPXREF101) are hard to apply to a `UIWebView` since you don't really have access to the raw drawing code, which would be the best place to plug that in.

**Addendum** Here's a sample drop shadow image: [image: drop shadow image]
.  It has 4 pixel cap size all around, for use with the above stretchableImage method, and an alpha of 80% (so it's 20% transparent in the middle, tapering out at the edges).  Feel free to use it.  They're easy to make with a selection + feathering in your favorite graphics app.